Non-transformed Log scale response variable in LMM - which distribution to use?
I am currently modelling tea bag index results across different forest "treatments" to infer differences, effect sizes and influence of covariates. One element of these results and a response variable I want to examine is already on the log scale. I have already checked and the data approximates a gamma dist and model fitting to a Gaussian dist is inappropriate. My question is does it make sense to use this in a GLMM and model the data over a gamma dist?

A plot of the raw data and a plot ofvte residuals from a simple linear regression would be useful.   And are you saying the after transformation the response resembles a gamma distribution?
